# Angular Error: error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<ITimesheetComments[]>'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm fairly new to Angular and was hoping someone could help with the following error I am getting.

> error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type
> 'Observable<ITimesheetComments[]>'. Type '{}' is missing the following
> properties from type 'ITimesheetComments[]': length, pop, push,
> concat, and 28 more.

The TimesheetCommentsService.getList() function calls the HttpService.getList() function which should return ITimesheetComments[].  Presumably I am missing a cast of some sort somewhere?

timesheet-comments.services.ts

```
import { ITimesheetComments } from './../models/timesheet-comments.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { ResourceParams } from '../../../core/http/models/resource-params.model';
import { HttpService } from '../../../core/http/http.service';

@Injectable()
export class TimesheetCommentsService {

    constructor(private http: HttpService) { }

    getList(transactionRelatedNum : number) : Observable<ITimesheetComments[]> {
        let resourceParams : ResourceParams = new ResourceParams();
        resourceParams.orderBy = "date_created desc";
        let endpoint: string = `ServiceReceipts/${transactionRelatedNum}/Comments`;
        return this.http.getList<ITimesheetComments[]>(endpoint, resourceParams);
    }
}
```

http.service.ts

```
getList<T> (endpoint: string, resourceParams: ResourceParams = new ResourceParams(),  headers ?: any, useOnlyEndpoint: boolean = false)
{
    let url = `${(useOnlyEndpoint) ? '' : `${this.env.BASE_URL}/${this.URL_PATH}/`}${endpoint}${this.buildParams(resourceParams.toExtraParams())}`
    return from(this.appAuth.authenticateToken(this.token).then(() => this.httpGet(url, headers)))        
        .pipe(map((response : HTTPResponse) => this.parseData<ITimesheetComments[]>(response)),
            catchError(error => this.handleError(error, 'Get')));
}
```

Comment: you need to `return` httpGet result also..

Comment: Does the endpoint really provide an array or is it maybe an array within an object? Please check your network console for the endpoint response.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  The httpGet is enclosed in the return from(...) brackets?

Comment: This is a compile time error, so the error shouldn't be caused by the data returned from the end point.